# Django 1.10.3 Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: sites?

Tags: python, django

`Django 1.10.3` is giving me this error, but `django 1.6.11` giving me following error ?

```
==>sh my.sh init index run
    *** Initializing server on www.my_app.me:8080 with my.settings.base
    *** Running all tests
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
        "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: sites
```

[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397852/django-application-labels-arent-unique-duplicates-bootstrap3)

Please suggest me how I can resolve the issue ? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Check your `settings.py`. Your `INSTALLED_APPS` list has `'sites'` specified twice

Comment: I removed duplicated lines from ```settings.py``` that does not help

Comment: but now you would be getting different error

Comment: No, I am getting the same error and I am sure that there is no duplicate items. Thanks !

Comment: Does your code declare any classes that inherit from `AppConfig`?