# Error in migration of django app using celery

Tags: python, django, migration, celery

I'm using celery in my django app. I have setup celery as usual. But, when i try to migrate, it displays error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 111, in handle
    convert_apps=app_labels or None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 42, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 109, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.render(ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in render
    self.apps = Apps([AppConfigStub(label) for label in sorted(self.real_apps + list(app_labels))])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.populate(installed_apps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: djcelery
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: djcelery
  Apply all migrations: auth, contenttypes, admin, djcelery, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying djcelery.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 96, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 140, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in render
    self.apps = Apps([AppConfigStub(label) for label in sorted(self.real_apps + list(app_labels))])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.populate(installed_apps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: djcelery
```

I'm using django version 1.7.5 and celery version 3.1.17. In the sample code, only djcelery app is added in the app list in settings.py .

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels

Comment: But i don't have any apps added to the project. Celery is installed using pip and djcelery is added to the installed_app list. So, there is no app-package conflict.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that I had the same problem. I tried to find duplicate names on installed apps and even modules named djcelery inside other packages. Didn't find anything to help. In my case, the app was running fine in some machines, but was failing in others. I could even make it run, but migrate kept failing.

What solved my problem was to reinstall all my pip packages. Supposing that you have all your packages listed in a file requirements.txt:

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

and then

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I think this problem may be caused by a dead pyc or a bad dependency chain. I also found a problem with mysql for python being installed partially by pip and part by apt-get (running on Ubuntu). You can check this running your command like:

```
python -m pdb manage.py migrate
```

The error reported by pdb was related to a bad connection. Without pdb I had the same message as yours.

Tested on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.6, pip 6.1.1, django 1.7, celery 3.1.8, django-celery-3.1.16.

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely stems from the fact that `djcelery` appears in both `unmigrated` and `migrated` apps. From what I've seen this is usually symptomatic of having both `south` and `django` style migrations in the same app. In any case likely something is off with `djcelery`'s migrations directory.