# Django django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: dynamic_scraper

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-dynamic-scraper

Hello i am new to django_dynamic_scraper. as i have installed it and also djcelery but when i apply migrations it shows this error. i Google it but didnt find anything.
Please be specific that i will understand better

this is my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #third party apps
    'registration',
    'crispy_forms',
    # 'schedule',
    # 'south',
    # 'kombu.transport.django',
    'djcelery',
    'dynamic_scraper',
    # my apps
    'article',
    'search_engine',
    'socialnetwork',
)
```

when apply migrate

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: article, dynamic_scraper, socialnetwork, crispy_forms
  Apply all migrations: search_engine, sessions, admin, dynamic_scraper, djcelery, sites, auth, contenttypes, registration
```

this is traceback error

```
Applying dynamic_scraper.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 96, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 140, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in render
    self.apps = Apps([AppConfigStub(label) for label in sorted(self.real_apps + list(app_labels))])
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.populate(installed_apps)
  File "/home/suz/social-network-sujit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: dynamic_scraper
```

Comment: Please check if you have put djang-dynamic-scraper twice in the installed app.

Comment: @iamsujit possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels See if the linked post solves your issue.

Comment: @mascot6699 No i havent put twice just once 'dynamic_scraper'

Comment: @user2719875 the error is occured while i was making migrations, when i comment out the installed app 'dynamic_scraper' it works fine but no migrations for dynamic scraper and no tables.

Comment: comment out 'dynamic_scraper' and run migrate and syncdb and make sure there is no table named 'dynamic_scraper' then search in models of 'dynamic_scraper' for the term 'dynamic_scraper' if that help to find duplicate entry. allthough I myself just installed 'dynamic_scraper' successfully with no errors

Comment: @mascot6699 i have tried it but there is no term dynamic_scraper. and i installed it successfully just migrations are not applying

Comment: I migrated too with no errors. As its an package making migrations is not needed just run migrate however i think there is some other issue. Did you use pip install or cloned the repo?

Comment: i used pip. solved the issue i manually delete the packages and reinstall.