# Error: "Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: messages"

Tags: django

I'm in the process of upgrading a django app from 1.6 to 1.9 and I'm getting the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: messages
```

I made the changes described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319562) (and reviewed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#for-application-authors))
but afterwards, I end up getting

```
OperationalError: no such table: user_messages_message
```

when trying to view the records from the admin page.

I can re-create the app with a different name, I was just trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Django 1.7` release on, it has built-in support for schema migrations, please read the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/), perhaps what you need is to follow the [`Upgrading from South`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) guide? Hope that it can point you to the fix.

Comment: I did follow the guide on upgrading from South, But I did it before because I wasnt having this issue. Do I need to do it again now that I fixed it?

Comment: Ok good that you already followed it, well there are a couple of things you could try, if the data that you have in the DB is not important, you could try to delete the current DB, and create and empty one, and run again `./manage.py migrate`, if it does not help, then remove the migrations, and with a new DB run `./manage.py makemigrations`, and `./manage.py migrate` afterwards. If the data matters, then could yo please update your question with your custom `messages` App `models.py` file so that I can take a look, and do some small tests myself? Thanks in advance

Comment: I do have a production site that is live, but luckily there is no data associated with that particular app. I'll just create a new app with a different name.