# What is the process when renaming an app's label in AppConfig that is already in production?

Tags: django, django-models

## Background

I'd like to use the 3rd party Django app "Allauth" to save myself some time. Allauth requires you to add providers in INSTALLED_APPS, and their provider modules' names conflict with my existing apps. So I get the "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates:.." error. I know how to fix that as per [this previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels/24319562#24319562)

## The Issue

My problem is that renaming my app's label in appconfig causes migrations to fail with "dependencies reference nonexistent parent node". So I assume this is because the parent node has now changed, and now so do the database tables.

## My Questions

My existing app has a ton of data in production already so its not an option to start fresh. My questions are what are my options? Does Django not offer an option to rename the label for 3rd party packages instead? Am I really forced to perform a migration similar to the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will need to follow the steps in the answer you linked: [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app).

I am in the same boat (damn you allauth) and I found this ticket outlining the fact that renaming things using app.label is basically broken and there is no automatic upgrade path.

See here for the discussion: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23790