# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail, django-oscar

I am developing a django web project that uses the following packages/applications:

- sorl-thumbnail
- django-oscar

Here is a snippet of my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'registration', #should be immediately above 'django.contrib.auth'
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # ...
    'zinnia',
    'zinnia_tinymce',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'embed_video',
    # ...
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
        'compressor',
        'widget_tweaks',
    ] + get_core_apps()
```

When I comment out sorl.thumbnail, I am able to run the development server using `manage.py runserver`. However, if I uncomment the sorl.thumbnail line and try to run the development server, it throws an exception:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: thumbnail

Now, I am aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels) exists on this site, however, following the instructions in the accepted solution, i.e.:

- create a sol_thumbnail folder in same directory as the manage.py script
- create sorl_thumbnail/apps.py (see below)
- modify myproject/mysite/___init____.py (see below)

## sorl-thumbnail/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SorlthumbnailConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'sorl-thumbnail'
    label = 'sorl.thumbnail'
```

## myproject/mysite/**_init _**.py

```
default_app_config = 'sorl-thumbnail.apps.SorlthumbnailConfig'
```

Why is the fix above not working, and how do I resolve this issue?

BTW: I am using django-1.10

Answer (score 2):

I went though the same problem of duplicated applications, and following exactly the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels) I solved my problem.

The problem with your solution is that you have added `default_app_config = 'sorl-thumbnail.apps.SorlthumbnailConfig'` to `myproject/mysite/___init____.py`, but you should have added to `myproject/sorl-thumbnail/___init____.py`.