# how To resolve django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account django 1.5

Tags: python, django

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
  django.setup()
File "/**strong text**usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
  "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account
```

how to solve this problem? what is wrong or going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: foo" in Django 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels)

Comment: That traceback is not from Django 1.5, because `django.apps` wasn’t added until Django 1.7. In any case, Django 1.5 is insecure and unsupported, you should upgrade to 1.11 LTS at least.