# how can I avoid getting duplicates: account?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, email-confirmation

I am trying to install `pip3 install django-allauth` to prevent login before email confirmation, but at moment when setting up settings.py I get the following error. I don't want to rename all the project names, because it is going to affect the complete project. Is there a way to achieve this without too many changes?

```
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~/Documents/blackowl$ python3 manage.py makemigrations account
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_com
mand_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 95, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: account
```

```
# Application definition
​
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'allauth' , 
    'allauth.account' , 
    'allauth.socialaccount' , 
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github' ,
    'apps.website',
    'apps.account'
]
​
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
​
ROOT_URLCONF = 'blackowl.urls'
​
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
​
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this under **INSTALLED_APPS** :

```
'django.contrib.account'
```

Comment: the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.account'`

Comment: try to delete     'apps.account'

Comment: apps.account depends on other modules

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319562/6808714