# Django 2.2.9: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a big project for which I need to breakdown my application into different maintainable modules and I keep getting this error whenever I'm doing imports across different modules of the application.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: admin
```

for now I have a module named **asset_herarchi** and another module name **db_configurations**

In **asset_herarchi** I've the following two models:

```
from db_configurations.models import TableDataReferenceConfiguration

class Attribute(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        table_datareference_config = models.ForeignKey(TableDataReferenceConfiguration, related_name="data_reference_where_conditions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Unit(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

In **db_configurations** I've got the following model.

```
from asset_herarchi.models import Unit

class TableDataReferenceConfiguration(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    result_column_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    unit_of_measure = models.ForeignKey(Unit, related_name="UOM_Table_Data_Reference_Configuration", on_delete=models.SET(None) )
    behavior_rule = models.CharField(choices=Rule, null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)
    behavior_order_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    behavior_order_sorting = models.CharField(choices=Sorting, null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
```

As I've mentioned earlier I'm splitting the application into different modules for easy maintenance
For some business logic requirements I need to import the **Unit** model into the **db_configurations.model** file to create a relationship with **TableDataReferenceConfiguration** and I need to import the **TableDataReferenceConfiguration** model back into the **asset_herarchi.models** to create a relationship with **Attribute** model and at the same time I wish the Model **TableDataReferenceConfiguration** to be in a separate module for some business requirements.

Due to these imports between multiple modules I'm having the error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: admin`

when I comment the import from anyone of the .models file the core proceeds. can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels). This probably what you want to see.

Comment: Thanks @SadaqatullahNoonari , I saw that answer before asking this question that is not the problem I'm having.