# Import "users" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: python-3.x, django

I wanted to import my views.py file from my app "users" and the urls.py of the project. However, I'm getting an error that the "Import "users" could not be resolved".

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMV30.png)

The urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views       # Why is there an error?


urlpatterns = [
# Admin Page
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

# Homepage
path('', include('blog.urls')),

path('register/', user_views.register, name = 'register'),
path('profile/', user_views.profile, name = 'profile'),
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'users/login.html'), name = 'login'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name = 'users/logout.html'), name = 'logout'),
]
```

The app is also in "INSTALLED_APPS" in the settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'crispy_forms',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvQwK.png)

This is probably an easy-to-solve problem, however, I'm fairly new to Django and don't really understand why it says this is an error. In a similar project, everything works fine.

[No error in a similar project, where I did everything the same way as far as I remember.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrg23.png)

Answer (score 6):

In your root directory in the vscode left pane, there is a folder .vscode.
click on that and the following key:value pair of your directories ex:["./users", "./blog"] it will resolve relative imports. It worked for me.

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./users", "./blog"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error has come because you have app users and blog which you have not written in settings.py file in `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog',
'users',
'crispy_forms',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and include urls also in project `urls.py`

Comment: This didn't help and gave me another error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: users
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: blog

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319562/14457833