# Duplicate app naming issue in Django without renaming the app

Tags: django

I know there are a few other posts about this out there and renaming my `messages` app might solve the issue, but I don't want to change the name of my `messages` app, and the label solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels) just returns this error instead:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app label 'email.messages' is not a valid Python identifier.
```

And the above error is after adding the `label` and `default_app_config` fields to `MessagesConfig` like the other post suggests:

```
class MessagesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'messages'
    label = 'email.messages'
    default_app_config = 'messages.apps.MessagesConfig'
```

My `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # my apps
    # 'accounts',
    'subscribers',
    'django_filters',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'core',
    'messages',
    # 'messages.apps.MessagesConfig',
    # 'email.messages',

    # django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: messages
```

What's the actual workaround for this (other than renaming `messages` to a different app name)? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the label field cannot contain a period - changing from `label = 'email.messages'` to `label = 'email_messages'` works

Answer (score 0):

this is because of this

```
'django.contrib.messages',
```

if you want to have messages and don't want to rename it you have to comment this

```
'django.contrib.messages',
```

Comment: hmm what does django.contrib.messages actually do? I don't want to comment it out if it's important. If it's best to just rename it then so be it

Comment: I'm also getting this error if that is commented out: (admin.E406) `'django.contrib.messages' must be in INSTALLED_APPS in order to use the admin application`

Comment: 'django.contrib.messages', is for when you want to show user a message, for example on registration, if user used duplicated name or email, you raise a message, I'm glad you found your solution